# Automobile research

Tags: automotive-design

I am looking for a project in field of automobile engineering.So if any one can suggest what are the areas in which there is scope for development/improvement in automobiles

Comment: Best or shortest list is one showing things that don't need development / improvement.

Comment: Ok, atleast tell me those that doesn't require development

Comment: Automobile engineering is a very large area - you might want to narrow down what areas you're interested in - e.g. aerodynamics, safety, propulsion, energy storage, etc. I'd suggest you ask this in our chat room [the Pitstop](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/340/the-pitstop) where there's more scope for a more open-ended discussion

Comment: I can't able to access that room due to low reputation points.So can u suggest any improvements in efficiency of engine

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet is to ask a whether an automotive company wants you to do a project for them. That way, it's guaranteed your project has an actual need and is not of only academic interest.

That said, the areas where most improvements will likely occur are:

1. Driver aids. Cameras, sensors, radars, lidars, etc.
2. Partially or fully autonomous driving, although this is likely too hard for a beginner.
3. Energy efficiency improvements such as turbocharging, hybrid electric vehicles, better air conditioning compressors, electrification, etc.
4. Alternative forms of propulsion such as electricity, natural gas or hydrogen.
5. Connected cars with their vehicle-to-vehicle communication systems

I would myself pick connected cars from the list, because it's something that can be researched with little resources and there are plenty of good and valid ideas that can be developed further. The other ones in the list require more resources to research.

Answer (score 0):

To add to @juhist's answer, I'd recommend finding a local further education establishment (university/college/etc) that runs an automotive engineering course - most such courses include both projects and placements with companies within the industry, and will help you to get the necessary skills, ideas and contacts to get a foothold in the industry. It would also help you to be able to team up with other people with similar interests and tackle a much bigger project than you could manage on your own.